# Number theory True or false

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I have two questions that I need to determine if they are true or false and I'm unsure

(a) There exists a number field $K$ such that $\mathcal{O}_{K} \cong \mathbb{Z[x]}$

(b) If $K = \mathbb{Q(\sqrt{3})}$, then $\mathcal{O}^{\times}_{K}$ has finite order.

I think for (a) it may be true because if $K$ is monogenic number field then shouldn't $\mathcal{O}_{K} \cong \mathbb{Z[x]}$?

I'm unsure about (b), my guess is true but that quite literally is a guess

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a) $\mathcal O_K$ consists of all elements that are *integral* over $\mathbb Z$, which is to say all elements $a$ which satisfy an equation of the form

$$c_0 + c_1 a + \cdots + c_{n-1}a^{n-1} + a^n = 0$$

for some integers $c_i$.  Supposing there were a ring isomorphism $\mathcal O_K \cong \mathbb Z[x]$, then wouldn't the indeterminate $x$ have to also satisfy such an equation?

b) Consider an element $\alpha = a + b \sqrt{3} \in \mathcal O_K$ which is a unit.  Then it's not difficult to see that the **norm** $N_{K/\mathbb Q}(\alpha) = (a+ b \sqrt{3})(a-b\sqrt{3})$ has to be $1$ or $-1$.  With this in mind, you should be able to figure out what all the units in $\mathcal O_K$ look like and answer your question.